# Acentos con mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo una aplicacion y mi objetivo es que desde el formulario se ingresen los datos con tildes y ñ, y que en la BD se almacenen igual.

Resulta que al ejecutar la siguiente consulta mediante PHP con PDO (desde el backend de la aplicacion):

```
INSERT INTO familia VALUES(0,'áááéééíííóóóúúúñññ','A','','','');
```

En la BD se almacena como :

```
Ã¡Ã¡Ã¡Ã©Ã©Ã©Ã­Ã­Ã­Ã³Ã³Ã³ÃºÃºÃºÃ±Ã±Ã±
```

Que debo hacer para que la cadena se guarde correctamente en la BD?
El script de la tabla es el siguiente :

```
CREATE TABLE `familia` (
`fam_codigo` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fam_descripcion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`fam_estado` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`fam_usureg` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`fam_fecreg` date NOT NULL,
`fam_horreg` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `fam_codigo` (`fam_codigo`),
KEY `fam_codigo_2` (`fam_codigo`),
KEY `fam_codigo_3` (`fam_codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=92 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Answer (score 3):

necesitarias cambiar tu charset a uno que acepte acentros y ñ

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;


ALTER TABLE familia CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Ya está usando `utf8mb4` en la conexión. Debería usar el mismo en la tabla